# How to add multiple dropdown form with submit button combine value and go to url

Tags: javascript, jscript

I want the submit button to act on the combined values in the two didferent dropwdown menu's in the form.

For example... west and winter is a different URL then west and summer

I'm struggeling for days to make this work. I feel some how this must be possible. Please help!

This is the code I use. When I replace the value to a URL. The URL will be loaded on submit (go). I want the values of the first dropdown and second dropdown to be counted and the result should be a URL on submit. Finaly there should be 16 different URLs.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".go-btn").click(function () {
location = $("#selection option:selected").val();
});
});
```

```html
<div class="selCont">
<h2>pick an option</h2>

<select id="selection" name="selection">
<option value="1">West</option>
<option value="2">East</option>
<option value="3">North</option>
<option value="4">South</option>
</select>

<select id="selection" name="selection">
<option value="1">Winter</option>
<option value="2">Spring</option>
<option value="3">Summer</option>
<option value="4">Fall</option>

</select>
<button class="go-btn" type="submit">Go</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, is your URL going to contain the values (i.e., 1, 2, etc...) or do you need the text (i.e., West, East, etc...)?

Comment: `id` should be unique

Comment: I'm just finding code online and this was the closest but if anyone can help out would be great. I need to have 2 dropdowns. 

Dropdown 1 will have eg: 1. I am working with my hands, 2. I am working with my feet, 3. I am working with my body. 

Dropdown 2 will have eg: 1. Acne, 2. Dry Skin, 3. Redness, 4. Sensitive Skin.

I need to be able to do the following: If user selects eg: from Dropdown 1: I am working with hands and Dropdown 2: Dry Skin ... when the user clicks submit it will take them to a URL eg: www.google.ca

Comment: @MarceloParra There are a couple of answers now that should give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $( ".go-btn" ).click(function() {
        // Grab text from select boxes
        var firstSelection = $( "#selection1 option:selected" ).text();
        var secondSelection = $( "#selection2 option:selected" ).text();

        // Set URL, change as necessary
        var url = "http://www.example.com/" + firstSelection + "/" + secondSelection;

        // Redirect
        window.location.href = url;
    });
});
```

Also, change the IDs on your select boxes:

```
<select id="selection1">
    <option value="1">Hands</option>
    <option value="2">Feet</option>
    <option value="3">Body</option>
</select>
<select id="selection2">
    <option value="1">Acne</option>
    <option value="2">Dry Skin</option>
    <option value="3">Redness</option>
    <option value="4">Sensitivity</option>
</select>
```

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Try giving both selector elements a unique id. Here's a working snippet:

```js
(function () {
  
  $(".go-btn").on(
    'click', 
     function (e) {
       // within this function you should figure out the url
       // to redirect to, depending on the selected values
       // the next line only shows the text of selected values
       $('#selected').html([$('#select1 option:selected').text(), 
                            $('#select2 option:selected').text()].join('/'));
  });
  
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selCont">
  
  <h2>pick an option</h2>

  <select id="select1">
    <option value="1" selected>West</option>
    <option value="2">East</option>
    <option value="3">North</option>
    <option value="4">South</option>
  </select>

  <select id="select2">
    <option value="1" selected>Winter</option>
    <option value="2">Spring</option>
    <option value="3">Summer</option>
    <option value="4">Fall</option>
  </select>

  <button class="go-btn" type="submit">Go</button>
  
</div>
<div id="selected"></div>
```

Comment: I'm just finding code online and this was the closest but if anyone can help out would be great. I need to have 2 dropdowns. Dropdown 1 will have eg: 1. I am working with my hands, 2. I am working with my feet, 3. I am working with my body. Dropdown 2 will have eg: 1. Acne, 2. Dry Skin, 3. Redness, 4. Sensitive Skin. I need to be able to do the following: If user selects eg: from Dropdown 1: I am working with hands and Dropdown 2: Dry Skin ... when the user clicks submit it will take them to a URL eg: www.google.ca

Answer (score 0):

So what I need to do now is for example:
If a user selects:

I am: "Someone who works with my hands"
and I need: "UV Protection"

Once they click Go it will take them eg: http://glysomed.bydecosta.com/portfolio-item/hand-cream-frag-free/

or

If user clicks:
I am: "Someone who works with my feet"
and I need: "Acne"

Once they click Go it will take them eg: http://glysomed.bydecosta.com/portfolio-item/foot-balm/

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $( ".go-btn" ).click(function() {
        // Grab text from select boxes
        var firstSelection = $( "#selection1 option:selected" ).text();
        var secondSelection = $( "#selection2 option:selected" ).text();

        // Set URL, change as necessary
        var url = "http://www.example.com/" + firstSelection + "/" + secondSelection;

        // Redirect
        window.location.href = url;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selCont">
  
  <h2>Me Time</h2>

I Am:
  <select id="select1">
   <option value=" " selected="selected">- Select -</option>
    <option value="1">Someone who works with my hands</option>
    <option value="2">Someone who works wit my feet</option>
    <option value="3">Someone who works with my body</option>
  </select>

and I need:
  <select id="select2">
    <option value=" " selected="selected">- Select -</option>
    <option value="1">UV Protection</option>
    <option value="2">Acne</option>
    <option value="3">Dry Skin</option>
    <option value="4">Eczema</option>
    <option value="5">Itchy Relief</option>
    <option value="6">Redness</option>
    <option value="7">Sensitive Skin</option>
  </select>

  <button class="go-btn" type="submit">Go</button>
  
</div>
<div id="selected"></div>
```